# How to create a desktop entry for an application located in the user space?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

I compiled the latest QGIS sources into `~/bin/qgis`. I can start the application from the command line running `~/bin/qgis/bin/qgis`. Now I want to have application launcher entry. So I copied the `.desktop` file of the QGIS distribution installation:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/qgis.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Next I renamed it:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
mv qgis.desktop qgis-custom.desktop
```

Next I edited the paths for `TryExec` and `Exec` in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=QGIS Desktop Latest
Version=1.0
GenericName=Geographic Information System
GenericName[ar]=نظام المعلومات الجغرافي
# other translations omitted for brevity
GenericName[uz]=Geografik axborot tizimi
Icon=qgis
TryExec=/home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis
Exec=/home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis %F
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Qt;Education;Science;Geography;
MimeType=application/x-qgis-project;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/jp2;application/x-raster-aig;application/x-raster-ecw;application/x-raster-mrsid;application/x-mapinfo-mif;application/x-esri-shape;
Keywords=map;globe;postgis;wms;wfs;ogc;osgeo;
```

[(Old .desktop file)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8182893/)

Finally I try to start it from the Unity launcher. Nothing happens ....
One thing that I remember which is different is that I have to export the library path in the shell:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/qgis/lib
```

I guess this is missing for the application launcher entry.

Comment: Try `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/qgis-custom.desktop`. The desktop file must be executable.

Comment: @the_Seppi I tried this. No difference. Other `.desktop` files miss the `x` too but still work.

Comment: Did you try a Unity restart? Open HUD, then `unity --replace`

Comment: Then change Exec and TryExec to `(Try)Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/qgis/lib /home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis (%F)`.

Comment: @the_Seppi Bingo! Please convert your comment into an answer. I will be happy to grant you the answer flag. Thank you! `chmod` is not needed.

Comment: FYI "user space" has nothing to do with this question. An application is by definition "user space"; it is not defined as `/bin` as you wrongly appear to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you told us that QGis needs the path `~/bin/qgis/lib` in the library path, change the Desktop file as follows:

```
 TryExec=$HOME/bin/qgis/bin/qgis
 Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/qgis/lib $HOME/bin/qgis/bin/qgis %F
```

Comment: I compiled the sources to the same directory as before. However, [the desktop item is no longer recognized by Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526018/desktop-entry-does-not-appear-in-unity-launcher).