# Desktop entry does not appear in Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop, kupfer

I created a `.desktop` entry for a [custom QGIS installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127279/how-to-install-qgis-from-source-into-user-space) in `~/.local/share/applications`. For some reason the Unity launcher and [Kupfer](http://engla.github.io/kupfer/) refuse to index the entry - it does not show up.

Here is the content of `~/.local/share/applications/qgis-custom.desktop`. I left out the translations.

```properties
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=QGIS Desktop HEAD
Version=1.0
GenericName=Geographic Information System
Icon=qgis
TryExec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jjd/bin/qgis/lib /home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis
Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jjd/bin/qgis/lib /home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis %F
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Qt;Education;Science;Geography;
MimeType=application/x-qgis-project;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/jp2;application/x-raster-aig;application/x-raster-ecw;application/x-raster-mrsid;application/x-mapinfo-mif;application/x-esri-shape;
Keywords=map;globe;postgis;wms;wfs;ogc;osgeo
```

In a [former question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508043/how-to-create-a-desktop-entry-for-an-application-located-in-the-user-space) I found out that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has to be exported. The application successfully starts when I start it from the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TryExec` key should only contain the command without any parameters. If it doesn't exist (in one of the folders in `$PATH` if you don't use an absolute path) the entry may be ignored.

So just use

```
TryExec=/home/jjd/bin/qgis/bin/qgis
```

(or remove the line altogether)

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, the icon shows up larger and there is no application name written under the icon.

Comment: Try to use the full path to an icon with the right size or a scalable icon (SVG).

Comment: The icons are fine after a restart.